# Load code without using a button

Tags: javascript, html, onload

I am trying to change this code so that it no longer needs a button to tell me which browser I am using. I want it to pop up when the page loads instead of being on a button. If someone can show me the changes needed that would be great.

I tried changing to `btn.onload` and adding `body onload="btn"` but this does not work.

Current code (WITH BUTTON):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
  window.onload = function() {
    var btn = document.getElementById('btn');

    btn.onclick = function() {
      var isChrome = /Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Google Inc/.test(navigator.vendor);
      var isSafari = /Safari/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Apple Computer/.test(navigator.vendor);

      if (isChrome) alert("You are using Chrome!");
      if (isSafari) alert("You are using Safari!");
    };
  }//]]>  

</script>

</head>
<body>
<input type="button" style="cursor:pointer;" id="btn" name="btn" value="Detect browser!"/>

</body>
```

Comment: This is very easily googleable... hint... you can change two words and you have your solution.

Comment: My goodness, how much effort did you put in that? You just have to remove 2 lines, you have an event listener and a button. Guess what you have to remove in order to make the button disappear and the function to auto-execute!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is run it when the window is loaded.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var isChrome = /Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Google Inc/.test(navigator.vendor);
    var isSafari = /Safari/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Apple Computer/.test(navigator.vendor);

    if (isChrome) alert("You are using Chrome!");
    if (isSafari) alert("You are using Safari!");
};
```

Comment: `window.addEventListener('load',function(){…});` or even `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){…});` is also possible—just to mention it.

Comment: Glad I could help, have fun on your road learning Javascript!

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace `btn.onclick` with `window.onload`.

Comment: Sorry Im not an expert, I tried my best for a beginner. This was a one off little task I had to do and instead of spending another hour trying I thought I would ask the experts ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following lines of code:

```
btn.onclick = function() {
};
}//]]>
```

This will cause all of the contained javascript to execute when the page loads.

Comment: True, and we can see where that is.